# Database stream entries in strapi v4

Tags: strapi

I'm trying to stream a large number of rows from database to frontend. But stream is not available on Query API or Entity API.
It's available on strapi.db.connection which is a instance of Knex.
But I'm not sure how to feed the query filters as strapi filters structure is different from knexjs.
I wii appreciate any guidelines or documentations.